# Problem with Extension Methods and Generic Constraints

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I have a base interface and several inherited interfaces. There are extension methods for the base interface that modify the object and return a new instance of the base class (`IChildA.Touch() => IBase`, `IBase.Touch() => IBase`).

For one inheritance path (`IChildB` and descendants) i want to implement extension methods that return an object of the same type as the calling object (`IGrandChildB.Touch() => IGrandChild`). For this i would like to specify a single generic extension method that is constrained to `IChildB` descendants.

This works so far, but now the compiler cannot resolve the call from `IChildA`. It tries to use the extension method for the `IChildB` path and fails instead of using the extension method for the `IBase` interface. Is there an elegant way to fix this?

```
public interface IBase {}

public interface IChildA : IBase {}

public interface IChildB : IBase {}

public static class BaseExtensions
{
  public static IBase Touch(this IBase self) { return self; }
  public static T Touch<T>(this T self) where T : IChildB { return self; }
}

public static class TestClass
{
  public static void Test()
  {
    IChildA a = null;
    IBase firstTry = a.Touch();  //Cannot resolve to BaseExtensions.DoSomething(this IBase obj)
    IBase secondTry = ((IBase)a).Touch();  //Resolves to BaseExtensions.DoSomething(this IBase obj)

    IChildB b = null;
    IChildB touchedB = b.Touch();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your concrete use-case, but the example will still compile if you drop the non-generic method and instead constrain the generic method to IBase.

```
public interface IBase {}

public interface IChildA : IBase {}

public interface IChildB : IBase {}

public static class BaseExtensions
{
    public static T Touch<T>(this T self) where T : IBase { return self; }
}

public static class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        IChildA a = null;
        IBase firstTry = a.Touch();

        IChildB b = null;
        IChildB touchedB = b.Touch();
    }
}
```