# Extension methods with generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003117/problem-with-extension-methods-and-generic-constraints) question and i was curious why this deosn't compile.

Given this code, can anyone explain why the call to `IBase.Test()` doesn't resolve to the correct extension method?

```
public interface IBase { }

public interface IChildA : IBase { }

public interface IChildB : IBase { }

public static class BaseExtensions
{
    public static IBase Test(this IBase self) { return self; }
    public static T Test<T>(this T self) where T : IChildB { return self; }
}

public static class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        IChildA a = null; //Yeh i know its null but just testing for compile here..
        IBase firstTry = a.Test();  //Cannot resolve to BaseExtensions.Test(this IBase obj)
        IBase secondTry = ((IBase)a).Test();  //Resolves to BaseExtensions.Test(this IBase obj)

        IChildB b = null;
        IChildB touchedB = b.Test();
    }
}
```

The error i get is

`Error  166 The type 'IChildA' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BaseExtensions.Test<T>(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IChildA' to 'IChildB'.`

I had a feeling it is because it would be ambigous for anything that implements `IChildB` and wouldn't know which extension method to use, but the error message doesn't moan about that side of it and if you remove the `IBase firstTry = a.Test();` line then it compiles fine..

Comment: Your compiler error doesn't match the code you've posted (Test vs Touch). Please post the *exact* error from the *exact* code you've posted - otherwise we won't know what other subtle changes you may have made.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx for about a hundred people telling me I'm wrong that this is a sensible rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, the problem is that in the overload resolution process, the compiler finds all applicable candidate  methods *without* checking the generic constraints specified in the method, picks the most specific one, and *then* checks the generic constraints.

In this case, the generic method is more specific than the non-generic one (as after type parameter substitution, it's effectively a method with an `IChildA` parameter instead of an `IBase` parameter) - but it then fails the constraints.

I have a [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/) explaining this in more detail, and another one [using it in a horrible way](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround/).

Comment: Aha, makes sense now, i was having a wtf moment :)

Comment: I had a look through the second link. Just a question; Why is the argument defined as `T? ignored = default(T?)` instead of `T ignored = default(T)`? Am I overlooking something, or do they do something different? The reason I ask, is because at a quick glance one might assume that a nullable parameter _is_ valid because of the ?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, the point is that `T` is the non-nullable type, whereas `T?` is the nullable version... the `T : struct` constraint on `Nullable<T>` is what forces `T` to be invalid when it's a non-struct... because the *parameter* types (after substitution) are checked for constraints, even though the type parameters themselves aren't. When I'm writing evil code blog posts, "at a quick glance" is never a good starting point :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Are those blog posts still available somewhere?